# Responsive header with lightning web component

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, html, responsive-design

I have this code, it is a header with LWC, divide into three parts, but the problem I have that my display is not responsive, each part points to the other
The part 2 and 2 overlap the part 1.

How can I fixe this .

```
<template>
    <lightning-card> 
        <div class="slds-page-header">
            <div class="slds-page-header__row">
                <template if:true={MyObject.data}>
                    <div class="slds-m-around_medium ">
       
                       <lightning-layout style="width:100%;">
                        <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">

                        <div class="slds-size_1-of-3">
                            <lightning-layout-item  style="width:20%" >
        
                                    <div class="slds-m-around_medium styleStatut">
                                        <img style="height: 20px; display: block;     margin-top: -15px; " src={statut}  >
                                    </div>
                                <div class="position1">
                                    <tr><span class="titlePosition"><h1><strong>{Name}<br /> </strong></h1></span></tr>
                                        <br><br>
                                        <span class="titlePosition1"><h1><strong>{Formula__c}<br /> </strong></h1> </span>
                                        <br><br>
                                        <span class="titlePosition2"><h1><strong>{Type__c}<br /></strong></h1> </span>
                                </div>
                               
                            </lightning-layout-item>
                        </div>  
                        </div>

                        <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">

                        <div  class="slds-size_1-of-3">

                            <lightning-layout-item   style="width:45%" > 
                            
                                    <lightning-spinner if:true={isLoading} alternative-text="Loading" size="small"> </lightning-spinner>
                                    
                                    <template if:true={imageurl}>
                                                    <img src={imageurl} style="height: 185px; display: block;
                                                     margin-top: -30px; width: 350px; max-width: initial; 
                                                    "/>
                                    </template>                          

                                            
                                        <div style="margin-top: -65px; ">
                                            <div class="slds-m-around_small ">
                                                <lightning-file-upload  name="fileUploader"  accept={acceptedFormats} record-id={recordId} onuploadfinished={handleUploadFinished} onchange={saveFile} disabled={disableImport}>
                                                </lightning-file-upload>
                                            </div>
                            
                                            <div class="slds-m-around_small">
                                                <template if:true={fileName}>
                                                        {fileName} &nbsp; &nbsp; 
                                                </template>
                                            </div>
                                                 
                                    </div>
                                </lightning-layout-item>
                     
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">

                                <div class="slds-size_1-of-3 ">

                                <lightning-layout-item  style="width:35%" >
                 
                                        <lightning-map style="height: 185px; width: 60px;  margin-top: -30px; " 
                                        map-markers={mapMarkers}
                                        zoom-level={zoomLevel}
                                        center={center}
                                        onmarkerselect={handleMarkerSelect}
                                        selected-marker-value={selectedMarkerValue}
                                    >
                                    </lightning-map>
                                    <div class="StyleAdress">
                            <p >{Country}</p><br>
                            <p>{City}</p><br>
                            <p>{Street}</p></div>
                    </lightning-layout-item>
                
                </div>



           
            </div>
    </lightning-layout>                             

</div>
                  
                </template>
         </div>
    </div>
</lightning-card>
</template>
```

==> CSS

```
.StyleHeader{
    color: white;
    background-color: white;
}

.titlePosition2{
    color: red;
    font-size: 160%;  
    margin-top: -12%;
    margin-left: 8%;
  
    
}


.slds-page-header{
    background-color: white;

}


.styleStatut{
    margin-top: 0.5%;
    margin-left: -5%;
}

.position1{
    color: black;
    font-size: 160%;
    margin-top: -12%;
    margin-left: 8%;
    /* position: absolute; */
  
}
.StyleAdress{
    color: rgba(0, 153, 255, 0.973);
    font-size: 120%;
    margin-top: 15%;

    
}
```

New Version of the code :

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <div class="slds-page-header">
                <template if:true={MyObject.data}>
                            
                        <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
                            <div class="slds-col">
                            <div>
                                <div class="slds-m-around_medium styleStatut">
                                    <img style="height: 20px; display: block;     margin-top: -18px; " src={statut}   >
                                </div>
                                
                                <div><br>
                                    <div class="position1">
                                    <div>
                                        <h1><strong>{Name}</strong></h1>
                                    </div><br><br></div>
                                    <div class="position1">
                                    <div>
                                        <h1><strong>{Formula__c}</strong></h1>
                                    </div><br><br></div>
                                    <div class="titlePosition2">
                                    <div>
                                      <h1><strong>{Type__c}</strong></h1>  
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                               
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>

                           

                            <div class="slds-col">
                            <div>
                                <lightning-spinner if:true={isLoading} alternative-text="Loading" size="small"> </lightning-spinner>
                                                                                    
                                <template if:true={imageurl}>
                                                <img src={imageurl} style=" display: block; 
                                                min-width: 120%; 

                                                width: 120%;height: 120%; 
                                                "/>
                                </template>    
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="slds-col">
                                <div>
                            <div >
                                <lightning-file-upload  name="fileUploader"  accept={acceptedFormats} record-id={recordId} onuploadfinished={handleUploadFinished} onchange={saveFile} disabled={disableImport}>
                                </lightning-file-upload>
                            </div>
                                <div style="margin-top: 50%; margin-left:20%">
                                    <template if:true={fileName}>
                                            {fileName} &nbsp; &nbsp; 
                                    </template>
                                </div>
                            
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            <div class="slds-col">
                            <div style="height: 50%;  width: 60% ">
                                <lightning-map 
                                map-markers={mapMarkers}
                                zoom-level={zoomLevel}
                                center={center}
                                onmarkerselect={handleMarkerSelect}
                                selected-marker-value={selectedMarkerValue}
                            >
                            </lightning-map>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                          
                            
                            <div class="slds-col">
                            <div>
                                <div class="StyleAdress">
                                    <p >{Country}</p><br>
                                    <p>{City}</p><br>
                                    <p>{Street}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>



                </template>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Now it works with this code except the image I upload, when I reduce the page it goes up and its size decreases. What can I do for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `class="slds-size_1-of-3"` then the style width would not work for the lightning-layout items. Please remove the `class="slds-size_1-of-3"` from the div elements.

Comment: when I remove it , It is true that no part overlaps the other but once I reduce the page I find the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You're putting grids inside of grids (`lightning-layout` and `slds-grid` are effectively the same thing). Choose one or the other.

Comment: Even if I removed slds-grid, at first each part takes its position, one on the left, one in the center and one on the right but once I reduce the page their positions change

Comment: @SalesforceJuniorDev It's not that simple. You're mixing in `tr` (which is only for tables), `h1` and `strong`, etc. You may as well start over from the beginning, get the layout working first, then work on the formatting.

Comment: @SalesforceJuniorDev Here, start from [this](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/osQAmYeGm5sklPAL05p7/src/app.html?p=stories). I don't know what you're trying to accomplish, but this is what it should look like.

Comment: I already modified my code , could you check it please